# Cast an Int Array into a Double Array C++ with Decimals

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, casting, double, decimal

For example, I have the code of

int results[11][2] and I need to cast these values to a double d[11][2] with a specified decimal value, such as 4 places to the left. I have already seemed to cast the double, by throwing a (double) on the outside of the array before one of my algorithms. I cannot seem to figure out how to move the decimal value placeholder, and have searched this website and C++ library trying to find an answer. I saw something on vectors, but I am unsure of what these are. Some of my final answers are whole integers, such as 100, and some are decimals, such as 13.33.

Comment: C++ does not work this way.

Comment: So there is no possible way for me to add a decimal value place to an array?

Comment: "add a decimal value place such as 4 places to the left" are you talking about "moving the comma" by multiplication or division by a power of 10?

Comment: *So there is no possible way for me to add a decimal value place to an array?* -- Voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: I don't know how I'm being unclear, but I am not just talking about multiplication or division by a power of 10. I have int values in an array. I have casted these values to be in a double array to do part of my algorithm. Whenever I get my final answer, some values show decimal values, and some of the other whole number values show no decimal values. I essentially need to show ALL of the final results array to have decimal values, whether they are whole numbers or not. For example, if index at [0][1] is a value of 100, I need that value to be 100.0000.

Comment: I repeat: C++ does not work this way. The only way to do something like this is to create a new array, then copy the values from the `int` array to a `double` array. An array of `int`s does not transform into an array of `double`s just by the virtue of casting. That's not how C++ works. The reason you're seeing the strange values you've mentioned is because you are reinterpreted the raw byte patterns of `int`s as a byte pattern of `double`s, and you're also hitting undefined behavior, because the actual sizes of the arrays are different. `sizeof(double)` is more than a `sizeof(int)` (usually).

Comment: You need a loop to convert each `int` value to its `double` counterpart.

Comment: I suspect you are talking about **printing** floating point values with four decimal places. As in `std::cout << std::fixed << std::precision(4) << value;`

Comment: Okay thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense. To do this copying, would I declare a new double array, such as double d [11][2] and use std::copy to copy the original result[11][2] array into the new double array inside of a for loop?

Comment: Could you provide a short list of **input** `int` array and a corresponding **desired output** `double` array?

Comment: Sure. I would need a value 0 to be reiterated as 0.0000. A value of 100 to be 100.0000. A value of 50 to be 50.0000. A value of 25 to be 25.0000 and so on. However, this is a multidimensional array and I need the values only from [x][0] to be returned as these values, as the other ones can remain whole values.

Comment: `double`s don't care about how many decimal places you want. Why do you think you need 50 to be 50.000 ... to present it to the user in that way?

Comment: Yes. The user needs to see an error percentage at the end of the program, and I want it to be calculated in the form of a percentage rounded to 4 decimal places.

Comment: Code was invalid, changed std::precision(4) to std::setprecision(4) and it compiled correctly. I must have missed when he posted this typing my other comment. Thank you!

Comment: @TristanB IgorTandetnik already told you how to do that: std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty to put the findings from the comments in some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

// only for dirty random numbers:
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

    int foo[11][2];

    // some data:
    for (auto &f : foo)
        for (auto &i : f)
            i = rand();

    // copy to an array of arrays of doubles:
    double bar[11][2];
    std::copy(&foo[0][0], &foo[0][0] + 11 * 2, &bar[0][0]);

    // some calculation:
    for (auto &b : bar)
        for (auto &d : b)
            d *= 100. / rand();

    // output:
    for (auto &b : bar) {
        for (auto &d : b)
            std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(8) << std::setprecision(4) << d << '\t';
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
}
```

#### Example Output:

```
255.3750        155.6058
 45.7636        164.7974
 50.4983         99.8548
108.2106         90.2723
 42.8402         86.1336
241.4214        802.7950
175.9784         86.9273
 11.9571        741.2245
 95.0048        225.1073
 84.7645        389.8197
 39.6910          3.0909
```